# check if a row is updated - without checking affected rows

Tags: mysql

Is there a fast way to check if a row exists?

When updating a row with `UPDATE table SET field='test' WHERE id=n` is there a way to check if the row exists without checking affected rows after the query is done? If no fields are updated, then affected rows will return `0` even though the row exists

You could of course check if the row exists with `SELECT id FROM table WHERE id=n` before `UPDATE ...` but I'm looking for (if possible) a better/faster way

I'm using `mysql 5.7`

Comment: How can a row with a specific `id` exist and not be updated when you update it? Are you looking for a way to check if the row exists before or after update? First you're talking about checking it after UPDATE and then you're mentioning running SELECT before the update.

Comment: If you are looking to insert if a row with that ID doesn't exist you could use a insert or update on duplicate key statement. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: I think he means the case when `field` already has the value `'test'` (before the UPDATE statement).

Comment: If the row doesn't exist I want to throw an error

Comment: @ConsiderMe, if you update a row with the same values as the row already contains affected rows will return `0` even though the row with the specific ID exists

Comment: @clarkk Thanks for the clarification. As to after query is done I'm afraid there is no RETURNING (Postgres) or OUTPUT (SQL-Server) clause in MySQL. See http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/219882 as well.